# glsl refract cause inexplicable error

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to render a landscape (lit by a directional sunlamp), which partially is underwater, the sunligh should be refracted by hitting the water, which i tried to simulate using the glsl `refract(vec3 incidence, vec3 normal, float relativeIOR)`, but the resulting refracted direction causes the shader to break down, producing a fully black terrain color.

I have realized that the problem is, that in my shader i take the dot product of this refracted light direction and the surface normal and that this dot product returns something less than or equal to zero, this is the case even when is set the relative index of refraction to 1, as demonstrated here:

```
in vec3 surface_normal_worldspace;
in vec3 surface_location_worldspace;
uniform vec3 sunDirection_worldspace;
out vec3 color;

void main()
{
    vec3 water_normal=vec3(0,1,0);
    if (surface_location_worldspace.y<0)//if below water, use refraction
    {
         vec3 refracted_sunDirection_worldspace=refract(sunDirection_worldspace,water_normal,1.f);//logically this should result in no refraction at all, in other words refracted sun direction should be equal to sun direction, and the dot product should be equal, and not cause error
        color = vec3(clamp(dot(refracted_sunDirection_worldspace,surface_normal_worldspace),0,1));
    }
    else
    {
        color = vec3(clamp(dot(sunDirection_worldspace,surface_normal_worldspace),0,1));//in reality my shader is way more complex than this, but this is only to demonstrate the error
    }
}
```

I have (of course) tried multiple other values for the relative index of refraction, but the result is still always this (in this case sun direction is set to `vec3(0,1,0)`):

[image: Error]

It is most obvious that the dot product of the refracted angle is less than or equal to zero, yet i do not understand why this is the case, for when the relative index of refration is 1, then the refracted direction should be perfectly equal to the not refracted one.

Strangely enough, if i replace the `color = vec3(...)` with `color=sunDirection_worldspace` above water and `color=refracted_sunDirection_worldspace` below water, it seems that sunDirection_worldspace is so close to refracted_sunDirection_worldspace that i can not tell them apart.

My question is therefor, why do the refracted direction cause the dot product to result in less than or equal to zero (horriply breaking my shading), and how can i  use the refract function, such that this does not happen? (please don't suggest that i avoid using the dot product in my shader, that is not an option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since for "over sea level" your terrain is white, it appears like sunDirection_worldspace and water_normal both point in the same direction. That is the problem for refract. According to the definition [in the Khronos reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/refract.xhtml), eta=1 will only result in output equal with the input when dot(I, N) < 0.

Comment: It appears that i confused the sundirection (which is the direction from the fragment to the sun, as the shading i use require) with the direction that the light from the sun travels. The solution turned out to be to replace `refract(sunDirection_worldspace,water_normal,1.f);` with `-refract(-sunDirection_worldspace,water_normal,1.f);`